# how to create 3d Flipping animation android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have done animation like this:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

but I want to animate like box means between front and back layout give space. not stick layout together and between this space I give border so it create like box so when flip at that time it looks like 3d flipping.